# With base Scala packages, how do I turn this JSON array into an actual array?

Tags: arrays, json, scala

I have this JSON in a separate file:

```
{
  "TestModel" : [
    "select * from ci_lmaggregation.elementsytest where hash_aggregation_key = 0 ALLOW FILTERING ",
    "select * from ci_lmaggregation.elementsytest where hash_aggregation_key = 1 ALLOW FILTERING ",
    "select * from ci_lmaggregation.elementsytest where hash_aggregation_key = 2 ALLOW FILTERING "
  ]
}
```

And using this scala package `scala.util.parsing.json.JSON` I've got to turn it into an array. Trying to run the queries contained therein in parallel for a POC. I've got this thus far:

```
  val input_file = "[path]/FeatureMapping.json"
  val json_content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(input_file).mkString
  val json_data = JSON.parseFull(json_content).getOrElse(0)
```

Which, when I print it out, is a map. But when I try to just use `toArray` it says `value toArray is not a member of Any`.

So I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish what I want to do. All the google results for this issue seem to be using packages that aren't base and we have strict dependency rules.

Comment: `scala.util.parsing.json` is more than deprecated and should never ever be used. Choose another lib

Comment: ah, thank you - which one should I use? there are like fifty, argonaut seems good?

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/yanns/scala-json-parsers-performance